# Intel vector instruction to zero-extend 8 4-bit values packed in a 32-bit int to a __m256i?

Tags: sse, avx, avx2

as the question says, I have a normal int that is 8 packed values of 4 bits each, and I would like to zero-extend that into a 256-bit vector register. Is that possible with sse/avx/avx2 ?

Comment: The answer is yes. Going from 8bit to 32bit is easy, e.g., using `_mm256_cvtepu8_epi32`. To get 8bit integers from 4bit integers, you need to do some shift- and bit-and operations. Do you care if the order of the result is kept as in the source?

Comment: @chtz yes, the order is important. Also this is in a hot loop that runs in about 15 cycles per iteration, so adding a lot of instructions (or one expensive instruction) might kill performance.

Comment: Actually, the exact order is not important, but it is important that the number of leading and trailing zeros is preserved. E.g. it would be fine to convert 0,0,0,0,1,2,0,0 to 0,0,0,0,2,1,0,0 , but not to 0,2,0,0,1,0,0,0

Comment: Yes obviously unpacking means to the bottom of a SIMD element (cases where that doesn't matter are rare, e.g. `popcnt`), but flexible order of elements allows e.g. lower-latency in-lane shuffles or maybe even fewer uops, instead of probably having to set up for a `vpmovzxbd`.  (`_mm256_cvtepu8_epi32`) like chtz's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [solution by chtz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55084225) (called `cvt_nib_epi32_chtz` in the remainder) is very suitable 
for general purposes. However, in some specific cases, the solutions presented below might 
be slightly more efficient:

```c
/*     gcc -O3 -m64 -Wall -march=skylake cvt_nib_epi32.c     */
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

__m256i cvt_nib_epi32_SKL(uint32_t x) {                /* Efficient on Intel Skylake and newer         */
                                                       /* Broadcast x to 8 elements                    */
    __m256i input   = _mm256_set1_epi32(x);            
                                                       /* Shift the nibbles to the right position      */
    __m256i shifted = _mm256_srlv_epi32(input,_mm256_set_epi32(28,24,20,16,12,8,4,0)); 
                                                       /* Mask off the unwanted bits and return        */
            return _mm256_and_si256(shifted, _mm256_set1_epi32(0xF)); 
}


__m256i cvt_nib_epi32_HSW(uint32_t x) {                /* Efficient on intel Haswell and Broadwell     */
                                                       /* Very inefficient in AMD Zen!                 */
    __uint64_t x_b = _pdep_u64(x, 0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F); /* Expand nibbles to bytes                      */
    __m128i    x_v = _mm_cvtsi64_si128(x_b);           /* Move x_b from GPR to AVX vector register     */
    return _mm256_cvtepu8_epi32(x_v);                  /* Convert bytes to integer elements and return */
}
```

---

The following assembly is [generated by gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/xpFBfc):

```
cvt_nib_epi32_SKL:
        vmovd   xmm0, edi
        vpbroadcastd    ymm0, xmm0
        vpsrlvd ymm0, ymm0, YMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        vpand   ymm0, ymm0, YMMWORD PTR .LC1[rip]
        ret
cvt_nib_epi32_HSW:
        movabs  rax, 1085102592571150095
        mov     edi, edi
        pdep    rdi, rdi, rax
        vmovq   xmm0, rdi
        vpmovzxbd       ymm0, xmm0
        ret
cvt_nib_epi32_chtz:
        vmovd   xmm0, edi
        vpsrld  xmm1, xmm0, 4
        vpunpcklbw      xmm0, xmm0, xmm1
        vpand   xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR .LC2[rip]
        vpmovzxbd       ymm0, xmm0
        ret
```

Function `cvt_nib_epi32_chtz` is very suitable for the AMD zen microarchitecture, 
because it doesn't use instructions `pdep` and `vpsrlvd`, which are slow on these processors.

On Intel processors, `cvt_nib_epi32_chtz` may suffer
from high port 5 (p5) pressure, depending on the surrounding code,
because `vmovd`, `vpunpcklbw`, and `vpmovzxbd`, all execute on p5.
The other functions decode to only 2 p5 uops.

The Skylake solution `cvt_nib_epi32_SKL` uses the `vpsrlvd`, which is slow
on Intel Haswell and Broadwell. 
For these processors `cvt_nib_epi32_HSW` is suitable. It uses the BMI2 instruction `pdep`, which is very(!) slow on
the AMD zen microarchitecture. Note that `cvt_nib_epi32_HSW` should also work well on Intel Skylake, but 
(again) the actual performance depends on the surrounding code.

Note that in a loop context the constant loading, such as `YMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]`, and `movabs  rax, 1085102592571150095`, 
is likely hoisted out of the loop. In that case only 4 uops are needed by 
`cvt_nib_epi32_HSW` and `cvt_nib_epi32_SKL`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that should keep the order:

```
__m256i foo(int x) {
    __m128i input = _mm_cvtsi32_si128(x);
    __m128i even  = input;
    // move odd nibbles to even positions:
    __m128i odd   = _mm_srli_epi32(input,4);
    // interleave: (only lower 64bit are used)
    __m128i inter = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(even, odd);
    // mask out wrong nibbles:
    __m128i masked = _mm_and_si128(inter, _mm_set1_epi32(0x0f0f0f0f));
    // convert to 32bit:
    return _mm256_cvtepu8_epi32(masked);
}
```

Godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/8RLUVE

You could get slightly more efficient, if you load two or four `int32` at once for the interleaving and masking of the even and odd nibbles. (This would result in multiple `__m256i` vectors, of course)